# 404 errors due to specific combination of .htaccess rules

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, magento, http-status-code-404

Using Magento 2.1.5, all files in a specific folder (`pub/media`, if relevant) generate 404 errors. I've tracked it down to the folder's `.htaccess` file. It seems to originate from a combination of the following three rules:

- `Options All -Indexes`
- `AddHandler cgi-script .php .pl .py .jsp .asp .htm .shtml .sh .cgi`
- `Options -ExecCGI`

If I have any of the three active, a 404 is generated.

I've searched high and low, but I can't find any concrete information on why this particular combination of rules would cause files to be inaccessible. Would anybody have any idea, or be able to push me into the right direction?

For now I've simply commented them out, which works fine. However, I'm not sure what the implications of doing so are exactly, so I'm not too comfortable doing so on a production environment. Other than that I'm just very interested to know why this is happening.

I'm running PHP 7.1.4 with FPM/FastCGI on Apache 2.4.25.

Thanks in advance!

PS If this is a question more suited for Magento's own Stack Exchange, please let me know! :-) I just figured it's a more general issue.

Comment: `Options All -Indexes` - Probably not the cause of your problem, but this statement is invalid. You shouldn't mix `+`/`-` options with those without. What files are in this specific folder?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's Magento's default `.htaccess`. They seem to all be images.

Comment: I can't see any reason why any of those directives would result in such an error - that doesn't really make sense. I think there must be "something else" going on?! Presumably you are requesting these "images" directly and not being fetched via another script? (Ah, that would seem to be a special case regarding the `All -Indexes`!)